# $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are linearly dependent and $u_2,u_3,u_4$ are linearly independent. Then $u_4$ is not a linear combination of $u_1,u_2,u_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space.
Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\in V$. Suppose that $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are linearly dependent and that $u_2,u_3,u_4$ are linearly independent.

Show that $u_4$ is not a linear combination of $u_1,u_2,u_3$

Since $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are linearly dependent, $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ are also linearly dependent. But how can I know whether $u_4\in<u_1,u_2,u_3>$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

> $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are linearly dependent $\Rightarrow u_1\in \text{span}_F\{u_2,u_3\}$

So, if $u_4$ was a linear combination of $u_1,u_2,u_3$, it would be same as saying that $u_4$ is the linear combination of $u_2$ and $u_3$ which contradicts the fact that $u_2,u_3,u_4$ are linealy independent.

**Edit:** To prove first line

> $\{u_2,u_3\}$ is linearly independent. **(why?)** and $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ linearly dependent. (Consider $a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3u_3=0$ what happens when $a_1= 0$?)

Comment: $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are linearly dependent means there exists a vector in the linear combination of the other vectors right? So how you know that $u_1\in <u_2,u_3>$?

Comment: **Hint:** $\{u_2,u_3\}$ is linearly independent. **(why?)** and $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ linearly dependent. (Consider $a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3u_3=0$ what happens when $a_1= 0$?)

Answer (score 0):

Since $u_1, u_2, u_3$ are linearly independent, by definition there exist scalars $c_1, c_2, c_3$, at least one of which is nonzero, such that $0 = c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 + c_3 u_3$. Note that we cannot have $c_1 = 0$, for if $c_1$ were 0, we'd have $c_2 u_2 + c_3 u_3 = 0$ with at least one of $c_2$ or $c_3$ nonzero, contradicting the fact that $u_2, u_3, u_4$ are linearly independent. Thus $c_1 \ne 0$ and $u_1 = -\frac{c_2}{c_1} u_2 - \frac{c_3}{c_1} u_3$, so by definition $u_1 \in \text{span}\{u_2, u_3\}$. From here, proceed as Swapnil Tripathi suggested. Hope this helps :)